# Override Up Navigation to only call finish();

Tags: android

Having an issue where I'm passing data from Activity A to B, and when launching activity C from B, and using the up navigation from C to B (setting B as parent of C in manifest), the data no longer being in activity B.

However when I add a simple button on activity C and call finish(); - data still shows up in activity B.

I just want the up navigation to act the same way and just call finish(); , nothing more or less. Any ideas?